# Using Apache Lucene to search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene

I've been trying to implement Lucene to make the searching on my website faster.

My code currently works, however, I think I am not correctly making use of Lucene. Right now, my search query is `productName:asterisk(input)asterisk` - I can't imagine this is what you're supposed to do to find all products where `productName` contains `input`. I think it has something to do with the way I save the fields to a document.

My code:

LuceneHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Lucene.Net;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Rentpro.Models;
using RentPro.Models.Tables;
using RentProModels.Models;

namespace RentPro.Helpers
{
    public class LuceneHelper
    {
        private const Lucene.Net.Util.Version Version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;
        private bool IndicesInitialized;
        private List<Language> Languages = new List<Language>();

        public void BuildIndices(DB db)
        {
            Languages = GetLanguages(db);
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version);
            List<Product> allProducts = db.GetAllProducts(true, false);
            foreach (Language l in Languages)
            {
                BuildIndicesForLanguage(allProducts, analyzer, l.ID);
            }
            IndicesInitialized = true;
        }

        private void BuildIndicesForLanguage(List<Product> products, Analyzer analyzer, int id = 0)
        {
            using (
                IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(GetDirectory(id), analyzer,
                    IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
            {
                var x = products.Count;
                foreach (Product p in products)
                {
                    SearchProduct product = SearchProduct.FromProduct(p, id);
                    Document document = new Document();
                    Field productIdField = new Field("productId", product.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                    Field productTitleField = new Field("productName", product.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
                    Field productDescriptionField = new Field("productDescription", product.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
                    Field productCategoryField = new Field("productCategory", product.Category, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
                    Field productCategorySynonymField = new Field("productCategorySynonym", product.CategorySynonym, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
                    Field productImageUrlField = new Field("productImageUrl", product.ImageUrl, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                    Field productTypeField = new Field("productType", product.Type, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                    Field productDescriptionShortField = new Field("productDescriptionShort", product.DescriptionShort, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                    Field productPriceField = new Field("productPrice", product.Price, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                    document.Add(productIdField);
                    document.Add(productTitleField);
                    document.Add(productDescriptionField);
                    document.Add(productCategoryField);
                    document.Add(productCategorySynonymField);
                    document.Add(productImageUrlField);
                    document.Add(productTypeField);
                    document.Add(productDescriptionShortField);
                    document.Add(productPriceField);
                    indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
                }
                indexWriter.Optimize();
                indexWriter.Commit();
            }

        }

        public List<SearchProduct> Search(string input)
        {
            if (!IndicesInitialized)
            {
                BuildIndices(new DB());
                return Search(input);

            }
            IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(GetCurrentDirectory(), true);
            Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version);
            TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);
            MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version,
                new[] { "productDescription", "productCategory", "productCategorySynonym", "productName" }, analyzer)
            {
                AllowLeadingWildcard = true
            };

            searcher.Search(parser.Parse("*" + input + "*"), collector);

            ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

            List<int> productIds = new List<int>();
            List<SearchProduct> results = new List<SearchProduct>();

            foreach (ScoreDoc scoreDoc in hits)
            {
                Document document = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
                int productId = int.Parse(document.Get("productId"));
                if (!productIds.Contains(productId))
                {
                    productIds.Add(productId);
                    SearchProduct result = new SearchProduct
                    {
                        ID = productId,
                        Description = document.Get("productDescription"),
                        Name = document.Get("productName"),
                        Category = document.Get("productCategory"),
                        CategorySynonym = document.Get("productCategorySynonym"),
                        ImageUrl = document.Get("productImageUrl"),
                        Type = document.Get("productType"),
                        DescriptionShort = document.Get("productDescriptionShort"),
                        Price = document.Get("productPrice")
                    };
                    results.Add(result);
                }
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            searcher.Dispose();
            analyzer.Dispose();
            return results;
        }

        private string GetDirectoryPath(int languageId = 1)
        {
            return GetDirectoryPath(Languages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == languageId).UriPart);
        }

        private string GetDirectoryPath(string languageUri)
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\App_Data\LuceneIndices\" + languageUri;
        }

        private List<Language> GetLanguages(DB db)
        {
            return db.Languages.ToList();
        }

        private int GetCurrentLanguageId()
        {
            return Translator.GetCurrentLanguageID();
        }

        private FSDirectory GetCurrentDirectory()
        {
            return FSDirectory.Open(GetDirectoryPath(GetCurrentLanguageId()));
        }

        private FSDirectory GetDirectory(int languageId)
        {
            return FSDirectory.Open(GetDirectoryPath(languageId));
        }
    }


    public class SearchProduct
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionShort { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string CategorySynonym { get; set; }

        public static SearchProduct FromProduct(Product p, int languageId)
        {
            return new SearchProduct()
            {
                ID = p.ID,
                Description = p.GetText(languageId, ProductLanguageType.Description),
                Name = p.GetText(languageId),
                ImageUrl =
                    p.Images.Count > 0
                        ? "/Company/" + Settings.Get("FolderName") + "/Pictures/Products/100x100/" +
                          p.Images.Single(x => x.Type == "Main").Url
                        : "",
                Type = p is HuurProduct ? "HuurProduct" : "KoopProduct",
                DescriptionShort = p.GetText(languageId, ProductLanguageType.DescriptionShort),
                Price = p is HuurProduct ? ((HuurProduct)p).CalculatedPrice(1, !Settings.GetBool("BTWExLeading")).ToString("0.00") : "",
                Category = p.Category.Name,
                CategorySynonym = p.Category.Synonym
            };

        }

    }
}
```

How I call the LuceneHelper:

```
        public ActionResult Lucene(string SearchString, string SearchOrderBy, int? page, int? amount)
        {
            List<SearchProduct> searchResults = new List<SearchProduct>();
            if (!SearchString.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                LuceneHelper lucene = new LuceneHelper();
                searchResults = lucene.Search(SearchString);
            }
            return View(new LuceneSearchResultsVM(db, SearchString, searchResults, SearchOrderBy, page ?? 1, amount ?? 10));
        }
```

LuceneSearchResultsVM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Web;
using RentPro.Models.Tables;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using Rentpro.Models;
using RentPro.Helpers;
using RentProModels.Models;

namespace RentPro.ViewModels
{
    public class LuceneSearchResultsVM
    {
        public List<SearchProduct> SearchProducts { get; set; }
        public bool BTWActive { get; set; }
        public bool BTWEXInput { get; set; }
        public bool BTWShow { get; set; }
        public bool BTWExLeading { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSearchString { get; set; }
        public string SearchOrderBy { get; set; }
        public int Page;
        public int Amount;
        public String SearchQueryString {
            get
            {
                return Translator.Translate("Zoekresultaten voor") + ": " + CurrentSearchString + " (" +
                       SearchProducts.Count + " " + Translator.Translate("resultaten") + " - " +
                       Translator.Translate("pagina") + " " + Page + " " + Translator.Translate("van") + " " +
                       CalculateAmountOfPages() + ")";
            }
            set { }
        }

        public LuceneSearchResultsVM(DB db, string queryString, List<SearchProduct> results, string searchOrderBy, int page, int amt)
        {
            BTWActive = Settings.GetBool("BTWActive");
            BTWEXInput = Settings.GetBool("BTWEXInput");
            BTWShow = Settings.GetBool("BTWShow");
            BTWExLeading = Settings.GetBool("BTWExLeading");
            FolderName = Settings.Get("FolderName");
            SearchProducts = results;
            CurrentSearchString = queryString;
            if (searchOrderBy.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                searchOrderBy = "Name";
            }
            SearchOrderBy = searchOrderBy;
            Amount = amt == 0 ? 10 : amt;
            int maxPages = CalculateAmountOfPages();
            Page = page > maxPages ? maxPages : page;
            SearchLog.MakeEntry(queryString, SearchProducts.Count(), db, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
        }


        public List<SearchProduct> GetOrderedList()
        {
            List<SearchProduct> copySearchProductList = new List<SearchProduct>(SearchProducts);
            copySearchProductList = copySearchProductList.Skip((Page - 1) * Amount).Take(Amount).ToList();
            switch (SearchOrderBy)
            {
                case "Price":
                    copySearchProductList.Sort(new PriceSorter());
                    break;
                case "DateCreated":
                    return copySearchProductList; //TODO
                default:
                    return copySearchProductList.OrderBy(n => n.Name).ToList();
            }
            return copySearchProductList;
        }

        public int CalculateAmountOfPages()
        {
            int items = SearchProducts.Count;
            return items / Amount + (items % Amount > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }


    }

    public class PriceSorter : IComparer<SearchProduct>
    {
        public int Compare(SearchProduct x, SearchProduct y)
        {
            if (x == null || x.Price == "") return 1;
            if (y == null || y.Price == "") return -1;
            decimal priceX = decimal.Parse(x.Price);
            decimal priceY = decimal.Parse(y.Price);
            return priceX > priceY ? 1 : priceX == priceY ? 0 : -1;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example input list of products:
[image: ProductList]

Query:
`SELECT Product.ID, Product.Decription, Product.Name FROM Product`

Desired results:
[image: DesiredResults]

SQL Server query equivalent:
`SELECT Product.ID, Product.Decription, Product.Name FROM Product WHERE Product.Name LIKE '%Zelf%' OR Product.Decription LIKE '%Zelf%'`

Basically, `Zelf` is the input. I want to find all matches with product descriptions or product names that contain the input string.

Comment: There is no need to append field name to query text: `parser.Parse("productName:*" + input + "*")`, because you already done it here: `new QueryParser(Version, "productName", analyzer)`

Comment: Yes, but if I don't manually set the parser's query to `productName:*input*` it only returns exact matches, not matches that contain the input string.

Comment: How about `*input*` - without `productName:`?

Comment: Lucene discourages the use of a leading wildcard, as this requires traversing all the terms in the inverted index, which could be slow. Please provide some sample data, along with more precise requirements - maybe a different analyzer could do the job.

Comment: I have updated my post with some SQL server images showing an example set of data and the desired results, including their queries.

Answer (score 1):

ucene [not allows](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Wildcard_Searches) to use ? or * as starting symbols of the searching term. To overcome this issue you need to store in your index a sub-strings from any position of word to it end position. E.g. for word test you should put to index

```
test
est
st
t
```

I recommend to use separate field for that. Java example for case if you have a short field with one word like a product name.

```
for(int i = 0; i <  product.SafeName.length()-1; i++){
   Field productTitleSearchField = new Field("productNameSearch", product.SafeName.substring(i, product.SafeName.length()), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
}
```

After this you can use following query string
`productNameSearch:(input)asterisk` or use a [PrefixQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html) for searching product names containing `input`.

In case if you have several words in you field and for you will be enough to have some reasonable length of your input, then it will better to add for this field a [NGramTokenFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html). You if have limit on your input string from n to m you should create a NGram Token Filter with n minGram and m maxGramm. If you has word `test` and you limit 2 to 3 you will have in your index words

```
te
tes
es
est
st
```

After this you can search via string

`ngrammField:(input)`

Comment: It seems like author uses `Lucene.Net` and in version 3.0.3 it [allows](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/d1b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_wildcard_query.html) leading wildcards, but it can work slow.

Comment: Approach in answer should has a good performance, but leads to bigger index size.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. While I don't mean to doubt your answer, I don't think I'm supposed to add an index for every letter of the words I want to search. My search function should go through the index, and return all the products that contain the `input` string. Currently, I'm searching through a product's title, category name, category name synonym and product description. A description can be upwards of 250+ words.

Comment: Can you provide a more details about your requirements? Does input allow spaces in it? Minimum length of input? etc...

Comment: I have updated my post with some SQL server images showing an example set of data and the desired results, including their queries.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer your question but it is safer to use the `using` block in C#. In your current code, calling `dispose` can throw.

You're doing:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(GetCurrentDirectory(), true);
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version);

//...

reader.Dispose();
searcher.Dispose();
analyzer.Dispose();
```

Which can be replaced with:

```
using (IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(GetCurrentDirectory(), true))
using (Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader))
using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version))
{
     //Do whatever else here.. No need to call "dispose".
}
```

The above is pretty much a `try -> finally` statement where it tries to do whatever is in the using statement. If anything throws, the finally block disposes the resources opened/allocated.

Another way (comma operator.. if all variables are of the same type) is:

```
using (whatever foo = new whatever(), whatever bar = new whatever(), ...)
{
    //do whatever here..
}
```